# Can we insert image that is read as url in sqlite using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Hi I am developing a cross-platform application using cordova. I am trying to insert image within sqlite. I am reading image with `reader.readAsUrl`, This returns some data like this in base64 `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAA......`, I used firebase to upload image using this following code It really works so fine.

```
function previewFile()
        {
          var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();


  reader.onloadend = function () {
    var image = reader.result;
    if(file.type.match('image.*'))
    {
    preview.src = reader.result;
   fullimage =reader.result;
}
else
{
  alert("select an image file");
}
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
        }
```

**Html code:**

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Now when I try the same with Sqlite I am not able to insert this image.Can I use this data to insert into database. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance..

Comment: sqlite can store blobs. You could try getting the full image and making a blob from it, then inserting it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to do so is save image in file system of server or you can also use CDN. then save the location of image into database.

However you can use blob to save images into database directly. but when you retrieve it back you have to prepare image again before display.

Comment: Thank you.. Anyways I dont want to store anything online or in my server I need to store image in users mobile.So can it be in sqlite? or someother way to do it?@roudrabhaskarudu thammali